# org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Пытаюсь соединиться с бд используя hibernate. Есть 6 таблиц(2 из них для связи ManyToMany) и 4 POJO класса с JPA-мапингом.
Падает с такой ошибкой:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany, @ManyToMany or @CollectionOfElements: model.pojo.City.hotels
```

Вот POJO класс в котором ошибка:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CITY")
public class City implements Comparable<City>, Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "sequnce_id_generator_city")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "sequnce_id_generator_city", sequenceName = "SEQ_FOR_CITY_ID")
@Column (name="ID")
private int id;
@Column (name="NAME")
private String name;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=Hotel.class, mappedBy="city")
private HashSet<Hotel> hotels = new HashSet();
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="COUNTRY", nullable=false)
private Country country;
```

Вот pojo на который ссылается:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "HOTEL")
public class Hotel implements Comparable<Hotel>, Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
private String id;
@Column(name = "NAME")
private String name;
@Column(name = "STARS")
private int stars;
@Column(name = "DESCRIPTION")
private String description;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY", nullable=true)
private Country country;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "CITY", nullable=true)
private City city;
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name="HOTEL_TOUR_OPERATOR",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="HOTEL_ID"),
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="TOUR_OPERATOR_ID"))
private Set<Operator> operator = new HashSet();
```

Ошибка говорит о том что `model.pojo.City.hotels` должен быть коллекцией. Или я чего то не понял?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявите поле с абстрактным типом:

```
private Set<Hotel> hotels = ...
```

Из [документации Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#collections)

> **2.8. Collections**
> ...
> Hibernate uses its own collection implementations which are enriched with lazy-loading, caching or state change detection semantics. For this reason, persistent collections must be declared as an interface type. The actual interface might be `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.List`, `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Map`, `java.util.SortedSet`, `java.util.SortedMap` or even other object types (meaning you will have to write an implementation of `org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType`).
>
> *Вольный перевод:*
> ***2.8. Коллекции***
> ...
> *Hibernate использует собственные реализации коллекций, в которые добавлены  ленивая загрузка, кэширование и семантика изменения состояний. По этой причине сохраняемые коллекции должны быть объявлены с типом-интерфейсом. Могут быть использованы `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.List`, `java.util.Set`, `java.util.Map`, `java.util.SortedSet`, `java.util.SortedMap`. Другие типы тоже можно использовать, но в этом случае вам придется реализовать `org.hibernate.usertype.UserCollectionType`.*

Иными словами Hibernate подставит в `hotels` свою реализацию `Set`. Писать служебные коллекции под всевозможные реализации множества (`HashSet`, `TreeSet`, и т.д и т.п.) в данном случае неоптимально.